# coinb.in wallet balance does not match "confirmed balance"?

Tags: balance

Coinb.in wallet amount is different from "confirmed balance"? Is this because an earlier incoming transaction hasn't actually completed?

Comment: Did you check their fees?

Comment: fees for the incoming transaction?

Comment: .00012304 fee which I imagine is pretty low

Comment: coinb.in transfer in from localbitcoin

Comment: What is the TX number?

Comment: wallet balance reflects transfer in but I cant spend it because it says I have an confirmed balance that is lower

Comment: aa4cc320b1858eb3479e5fe09c28ef4f34e7aefd324b097526b62b5436a1fd01

Comment: Looks invalid: https://blockchain.info/search?search=aa4cc320b1858eb3479e5fe09c28ef4f34e7aefd324b097526b62b5436a1%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bfd01

You may have been scammed.

Comment: I was monitoring blockchain - what about it makes you suspicious?

Comment: That TX doesn't exist on the Bitcoin network.

Comment: https://blockchain.info/address/1PKYBH8vYjLMAXrpKmLSxYAx3F3sxk7kaz?filter=5

Comment: I found it on blockchain.info

Answer (score 0):

[Coinb.in uses blockr.io](https://github.com/OutCast3k/coinbin/blob/master/js/coinbin.js#L841) for fetching UTXOs. Blockr.io is currently 153 blocks behind the bitcoin network (not sure why).

```
Current Blockheight: 476961,
Blockr Blockheight: 476808
```

This is likely why you are having issues.

Comment: thank you for the info. So, blockr.io will eventually catch up?

Comment: Personally, I think it would be best if there was a pull request to replace blockr with another service, or even better, multiple other sources when fetching UTXO.